# Approximation of $\log(\frac{1-x}{x})$ to $\log(\frac{1}{x})$?

Tags: logarithms

I encountered this approximation in an Information Retrieval textbook, where they approximated:

$$\log(\frac{1-u_t}{u_t})$$
to $$\log(\frac{1}{u_t})$$

where $u_t\in[0,1]$ (tending towards 1, aka the probability of a frequently occurring value).

I don't understand how they arrived at this value. I've tried pulling it apart into $\log(1-u_t) + \log(1/u_t)$, but $\log(1-u_t)$ approaches negative infinity when $u_t$ is large (~=1), which meant that term couldn't be ignored.

Does anyone have any idea?

[image: approximation]

Comment: The last formula clearly uses the fact that $u_t << 1$. I think the statement in the second bullet must have an error; it should not say $u_t$ is the probability of term occurrence in nonrelevant documents for a query.

Comment: I've thought about that, but it doesn't make sense. Because of the paragraph in the screenshot: assuming $relevance$ is a small % of N, then N can be used to approximate $irrelevance$. As $irrelevance = u_t$, we can assume $u_t$ should approach $1$.

Comment: @HocNgo I thought it doesn't make sense too, but I just wanted to confirm that either I was wrong, or the paragraph was wrong haha. I think I will just accept that the paragraph is wrong then.

Comment: This makes sense for small $u_t \approx 0$ because by their Puiseux series (at $0$) we have $$\log\left(\frac{1-u_t}{u_t}\right) = -\log(u_t) - u_t + O(u_t^2)$$ and $$\log\left(\frac{1}{u_t}\right) = -\log(u_t) + O(u_t^2)$$ hence for small $u_t$ they are both approximately $$\log\left(\frac{1-u_t}{u_t}\right) \approx \log\left(\frac{1}{u_t}\right)\approx- \log(u_t).$$ As for $u_t \to 1,$ the assertion makes no sense.

Comment: $u_t$ is very small because it refers to "term occurrence in non-relevant documents", and relevant documents are very sparse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I searched through Google and think you are talking about page 227 in [this](https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/pdf/11prob.pdf), so I'll base my response on the information there. Because relevant documents are a small percentage, the probability that you find a term you are looking for inside a non-relevant document is very small, so$$u_t = \frac{df_t}{N}\ \ \text{is very small}\implies \frac{N}{df_t} \ \ \text{is very large}$$ Hence, $$\log\frac{1-u_t}{u_t}=\log\frac{N-df_t}{df_t}=\log\left(\frac{N}{df_t}-1\right)\approx \log\frac{N}{df_t}$$

Comment: Ohhh I get it now. The way it was phrased tripped me up. But your explanation made more sense. It wasn't about **"all"** terms, but about terms that **"you are looking for"**. Since relevant documents are sparse, the desired terms are sparse. So irrelevant documents naturally have `fewer occurrences of an already sparse term`, making $u_t$ really small. Your equation also made it v.clear how the approximation works. Thanks thanks!

Comment: Glad to help! I'm also interested in information retrieval so it was cool to read a bit about it :)

Comment: Good work, Lazy Lee!